# required namespace never provided -- ES6 Modules and Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library

I am trying to use ES6 modules while compiling my code using Closure. While it is discouraged, it seems supported.

I have tried to reduce an example to the minimum and this is my current situation.

**File Structure**

*Path*: `/user/.../myapp/js/`

*Contains*:

- closure.jar
- test/app.js
- test/module.js

*test/module.js*

```
const A = function() { return 'Hello, World' };

export { A }
```

*test/app.js*

```
import { A } from '/test/module.js'

const text = A();
console.log(text);
```

**Compilation Command**

Then, I run this command to compile my code:

```
java -jar closure.jar \
  --js test/**.js \
  --js_output_file test/main.js \
  --dependency_mode=STRICT \
  --entry_point test/app.js \
  --language_in ECMASCRIPT6
```

**Error**

I get the following error:

```
test/app.js:1: ERROR - required "module$test$module" namespace never provided
import { A } from '/test/module.js'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Questions:**
Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Thank you!

---

**Import Tests**

I have tried a few import options such as:

```
import { A } from '/test/module.js'
import { A } from 'test/module.js'
import { A } from '/test/module'
import { A } from 'test/module'
import { A } from './module.js'
import { A } from './module'
import { A } from '/module.js'
import { A } from '/module'
import { A } from 'module.js'
import { A } from 'module'
```

Different imports will throw different errors as they may not detect the file. Examples:

```
test/app.js:1: WARNING - Failed to load module "/test/module"
import { A } from '/test/module'
```

or

```
test/app.js:1: WARNING - Invalid module path "test/module.js" for resolution mode "BROWSER"
import { A } from 'test/module.js'
```

**Export Tests**

Using the original import:

```
import { A } from '/test/module.js'
```

I have also used a few export alternatives:

```
export function A() { return 'Hello, World' };

export default function A() { return 'Hello, World' };
```

Comment: This is a bug in closure-compiler. It should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Here's the PR to track the progress: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/pull/2641

Comment: @nitobuendia — did you resolve your issue? What did you end up doing? I'm trying to add Bazel support via `rules_closure` to to an existing NPM project, and facing the same issue. Please add an answer to this question with what you did, unless the new release just solved it for you automatically. Thanks!